# Pipe Maze: Installing Natural Gas Line to Weber Natural Gas Grill

Tags: natural-gas

Trying to Install my weber natural gas grill to the natural gas line that is already set up. The gas line has a 3/8 male flare connection.... and the weber grill needs a 3/8 male non-flare connection. I can't figure out what hardware I need to make this work, and I already broke one hose trying to jam it in.

A double flare female connector and then a male with one side flare one-side straight pipe? Can't seem to find that at your home depot/ace hardwares, any help?

Comment: You might have better luck at a fireplace/outdoor type store.